# OSSL_DECODER_from_bio returns false

Tags: visual-c++, openssl, x509certificate

I have problems loading pem certificates using the openssl api.

This is my code:

```
EVP_PKEY* CryptoModule::load_key(OSSL_LIB_CTX* libctx, const char* passphrase)
    {
        auto *b = BIO_new_file(our_pub_cert_file.toStdString().c_str(), "r");
       
        OSSL_DECODER_CTX* dctx = nullptr;
        EVP_PKEY* pkey = nullptr;

        dctx = OSSL_DECODER_CTX_new_for_pkey(&pkey, nullptr, nullptr, "RSA",
                                             0, libctx, nullptr);
        if ( nullptr != passphrase )
            OSSL_DECODER_CTX_set_passphrase(dctx, reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(passphrase), strlen(passphrase));

        std::ignore = OSSL_DECODER_from_bio(dctx, b);
        OSSL_DECODER_CTX_free(dctx);

        return pkey;
    }
```

The certificate that is opend with BIO_new_file is a RSA encrypted sha256 2048 bit certificate, which is valid.

Using this cert on the command line works fine.

our_put_cert_file is a QString, containing the full path. QFile::exixts() returns true on this path.

I've already tested
OSSL_DECODER_CTX_new_for_pkey(&pkey, "PEM", nullptr, "RSA",
0, libctx, nullptr);

and

OSSL_DECODER_CTX_new_for_pkey(&pkey, "PEM", "SubjectPublicKeyInfo", "RSA",
EVP_PKEY_PUBLIC_KEY, libctx, nullptr);

and

OSSL_DECODER_CTX_new_for_pkey(&pkey, "PEM", nullptr, "RSA",
EVP_PKEY_PUBLIC_KEY, libctx, nullptr);

What could be the problem?

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: "RSA encrypted sha256 2048 bit certificate". Is it a certificate or a key?? These are two different things (a certificate *contains* a key, but is not a key itself). `OSSL_DECODER_CTX_new_for_pkey` won't load a certificate for you. It loads keys. You can use `PEM_read_bio_X509` or `d2i_X509_bio` to load a *certificate* (use the former for PEM format or the latter for DER format). You can use `X509_get_pubkey` to get an EVP_PKEY out of the certificate.

Comment: Many thanks! After implementing your tip, I get a valid key.